# How to get chemical equations with diagonal arrows

Tags: equations, formatting, mhchem

I have a small working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \ce{
    S + E_1 <=> SE_1 -> P + E_1 \\ S + E_2 <=> SE_2 -> P + E_2 %Ask how to do this on Stackxchange
 }
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

This ends up giving 2 equation, but I want to merge these 2 equations together, into 1.

I am looking to have like have the `S + E_1 <=> SE_1` and `S + E_2 <=> SE_2` on the same line as each other (with only 1 `S`), but like at 45 degrees from the horizontal in both directions.

I'm really struggling to explain what I mean, but hopefully what I've put makes sense

Edit:This is what I mean https://gyazo.com/25902d106e90a628820075df6c023523

Comment: Perhaps if you could add a little sketch of what the expected result should look like, it would help (?)

Comment: @caverac Yeah sure, I'll try to do something like that now

Comment: Added what I mean

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `\ArrowBetweenLines` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\thickspace & \ce{E_1 <=> SE_1 -> P + E_1}\\
\ArrowBetweenLines[\ce{S}\enspace\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}\begin{matrix} + \\\\+\end{matrix}\!\!]& \ce{ E_2 <=> SE_2 -> P + E_2}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `tikz` may be an overkill, but here it is

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep = 0pt]
  \node[] (S) {$S$};
  \node[above right = 1pt and 3pt of S] {$+ E_1 \rightleftharpoons S E_1 \to P + E_1$};
  \node[below right = 1pt and 3pt of S] {$+ E_2 \rightleftharpoons S E_2 \to P + E_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may write `${} + E_1 \rightleftharpoons S E_1 \to P + E_1$` to have the right spacing around the  first `+` (and similarly for the second equation).

Answer (score 1):

Using `multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \multirow{2}{*}{\ce{S}}\thickspace & \ce{+ E_1 <=> SE_1 -> P + E_1}\\
  & \ce{+ E_2 <=> SE_2 -> P + E_2}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]